# Using Incrond Inotify but having issues with user groups/permissions

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, nginx, inotify

In the /etc/incron.allow I added both:

```
root
USER_1
```

Then I edited the incrontab so it looks like this:

```
/var/www/laravel/public/js/main.js IN_MODIFY yui-compressor -o /var/www/laravel/public/js/main.min.js /var/www/laravel/public/js/main.js
```

I think the issue may have something to do with permissions or perhaps groups but I'm not sure as I'm not getting anything when I check with `tail -f /var/log/syslog`

The `/var/www/laravel/public` folder is owned by `USER_1` in group `www-data`. Incrond Inotify is done by the `root` user. When the main.js file is updated shouldn't Incrond Inotify run regardless of the current user since it's been set by `root`? Why isn't it working and how can I make it work with either `root` or `USER_1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an issue with the PATH environment in incron. Try to add the full path to your program like this (I am assuming `yui-compressor` resides in `/usr/bin/`)

```
/var/www/laravel/public/js/main.js IN_MODIFY /usr/bin/yui-compressor -o /var/www/laravel/public/js/main.min.js /var/www/laravel/public/js/main.js
```

to find out which is the full path to `yui-compressor` run the following in a terminal:

```
which yui-compressor
```

If you have problems with corrupted output files, consider to use `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` instead of `IN_MODIFY` because that fires only once the file is closed and not on every write operation. Depending on how your editor handles edits, that may be closer to what you want or not.

Edit: This should work fine under your `USER_1` account. Just run `incrontab -e` in a terminal when logged in as `USER_1` and add the line I gave above.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work due to permissions still.

Comment: check that not only the folder but also the files in it are owned by USER_1. This is especially important if you use a build tool like grunt or jekyll which creates the files on the fly.

Comment: also, of course the files and folders have to have write (and the folders access) permissions.

Comment: You could try to put your command in a script and redirect the output to file to see what the problem is. such a script would contain a line like this: '/usr/bin/yui-compressor -o $1 $2 &>>/tmp/yui.log'. That should help debug why the command fails. Also, if 'yui.log' does not get created, the incron command is not executed.

Comment: one last tip would be to make sure that the incron daemon is running

Comment: /var/www/laravel/public/js/main.js IN_MODIFY /usr/bin/yui-compressor -o /var/www/laravel/public/js/main.min.js /var/www/laravel/public/js/main.js
/var/www/laravel/public/css/style.css IN_MODIFY /usr/bin/yui-compressor -o /var/www/laravel/public/css/style.min.css /var/www/laravel/public/css/style.css

The aboe is what have. The odd thing is, the .css file works but the .js file doesn't.

The original css file permission is rw-rw-r-- with the owner/group being USER_1/USER_1 and the output css is rw-r--r-- with the owner and group being root/root. Permissions/group for the .js file is the same.

Comment: sounds to me that you have some leftover in the root incrontab that creates the output with root ownership. Try to delete the root incrontab ('sudo -s' and then 'incrontab -e' and delete the line there) then chown the output that is owned by root to USER_1 and create the incrontab line for USER_1 then you should be all set. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The problem was due to permissions. It required the read and execute access of all parent and child directories to the file. It seems yui-compressor (Java) has to traverse the directories to get to the file. If it can't get to the directory, then it fails.

Comment: glad your problem is solved. and thanks for letting me know what the issue was.